# Using read.csv in R drops rows that have a NA in them?

Tags: r, csv

I am executing this line of code to import a file

```
flowers <- read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data")
```

149 rows come in.  The problem is that there are 151 rows in the original dataset.  When I look at the unique values for the last column (#5), the 2 rows with a "NA" are getting dropped:

```
unique(flowers[,5])
```

What do I have to do to include those 2 rows?

Comment: That did it.  Can you post it as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `blank.lines.skip=FALSE` in the `read.csv` to get the blank lines as well

```
flowers <- read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.dat‌​a",
        blank.lines.skip=FALSE)
```